# How to prevent SharePoint site page refresh itself when jquery .load is triggered?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, jquery, 2016

I have a simple SharePoint site page (created in Site Page library). I added a simple jquery syntax here:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#button_overview").on("click", function(){   $("#homepagecontent").load("../description/overview.htm");   });

});
</script>
```

When I click the button, overview.htm is loaded for 1 sec and the entire page is refreshed. It cause the page render back to previous stage.

I have also tried `.html("<p>hello</p>")`. The result is "hello" show up for 1 sec and page is refreshed.

Is it default SharePoint behavior? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding (Correct me if I am wrong), you forgot to add the `type="button"` to your button element.

So, Add `type="button"` to the button element like:

```
<button type="button" id="button_overview" onclick="yourFunction()">Click Here</button>
```

**Reference**: [prevent refresh of page when button inside form clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)

Comment: Hi @Mark L, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my post helped you in any way.